# Syntax in if-else block in bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm pretty new to bash shell script, I have the following:

```
CMD_MYSQL="${MYSQL_DIR}mysql --user=${MYSQL_USER} --pass=${MYSQL_PASS} ..."

if [ ($CMD_MYSQL --execute="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE \
  table_schema='$MYSQL_DB' and table_name='${tablename}_new';") -eq 1 ]; then
  ...
else
  echo "Table ${tablename}_new does not exist."
fi
```

You can safely ignore other variables.

I have syntax error near `$CMD_MYSQL` after `if`, I suppose because I try to call the variable `$CMD_MYSQL`. How should I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: try echo "`$CMD_MYSQL --execute="RENAME TABLE $tablename to ${tablename}_old`";

Comment: @RaghunandanKrishnamurthy Sorry, not that `$CMD_MYSQL`. Please see edited. The syntax error is in the `if` condition.

Comment: do you want to use the return code of the output of `mysql`? in the former case you don't need square brackets and `-eq` in the latter - you are missing `$` before `(MYSQL`

Comment: @bobah Yes, I just want to test the output.

Comment: Use acute/backquote - acute <command> acute

Comment: @RaghunandanKrishnamurthy Please submit your answer, I will test it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to test the output of the your command (and not its return code). Then the syntax should look like

```
CMD_MYSQL="${MYSQL_DIR}mysql --user=${MYSQL_USER} --pass=${MYSQL_PASS} ..."

if [ "$($CMD_MYSQL --execute="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE \
  table_schema='$MYSQL_DB' and table_name='${tablename}_new';")" -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "Renaming ($MYSQL_DB.$tablename)..."
  $CMD_MYSQL --execute="RENAME TABLE $tablename to ${tablename}_old;"
else
  echo "Table ${tablename}_new does not exist."
fi
```

note the extra `$` in front of the parentheses.

The parentheses, without `$` in front, create a subshell. With the `$`, they substitute with the output of the command in the parentheses.

If your query does outputs a more complex result than just a number, you might need to search for the number inside the result with something like:

```
if [[ "$($CMD_MYSQL --execute="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE \
  table_schema='$MYSQL_DB' and table_name='${tablename}_new';")" == *1* ]]; then
  echo "Renaming ($MYSQL_DB.$tablename)..."
  $CMD_MYSQL --execute="RENAME TABLE $tablename to ${tablename}_old;"
else
  echo "Table ${tablename}_new does not exist."
fi
```

Comment: What does you query return exactly?  If you get that error, it probably means your query returns several words, not a single number.

Comment: I guess I missed `-N -s` in my MySQL query. http://serverfault.com/a/334368/74192

Answer (score 0):

```
CMD_MYSQL="${MYSQL_DIR}mysql --user=${MYSQL_USER} --pass=${MYSQL_PASS} ..."

if [ "**$CMD_MYSQL --execute="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE \
  table_schema='$MYSQL_DB' and table_name='${tablename}_new';**" -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "Table ${tablename}_new **does** exist."
else
  echo "Table ${tablename}_new does **not** exist."
fi
```